# How do I filter a table using check list boxes and a button? (in Delphi 2010)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

This is the form I am working with:

[image]

It shows a basic Delphi form with a DB Grid on top with a panel underneath. The panel below contains two CheckListBox's and one radiogroup. Each CheckListBox contains three check boxes and the radiogroup consists of two radio buttons. There is also a button on the right of the panel with the text "Filter" on it.

**Question:** How can I select the check boxes and one of the radio buttons and then click the button to make the table filter according to the selection?

Comment: This depends on your database. You don't provide any information about that or what you have tried so far.

Comment: What's your database engine? Which drivers are you using? What database components are you using? What does your existing query look like?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The answer to your q is of course you can.  *How* to do it depends on the factors @JerryDodge asked about.  SO is not a site where we write your code for you, we help with specific programming problems.  You need to try writing some code and showing us what you've come up with.

Comment: Look at the Filter property of your Dataset. When the end-user pushes the Filter button, you should build an string with the condition corresponding to the user selections, assign it to that Filter property, and set the Filtered property to true. That Filter would be something like: "(Position = 'Defender' or Position = 'Attacker') and (PreviousTeam = 'A' or PreviousTeam = 'B') and Injured = False".